# Error in addressing an open Excel file, using VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to have a vba macro in PowerPoint to open and retrieve information from an Excel file.
The Excel file is saved in a SharedPoint and I am able to open it. However, when I want to refer to the Workbook as to retrieve information from it's cells, it gives me the following error: `Automation error invalid syntax -2147221020 (800401e4)`

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False         

    'open excel from sharedpoint
    ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink _
      Address:="http://teams.blabla.com/Shared%20Documents/Overview_NPD_Projects.xlsm", _
      NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True

    Set wb = GetObject("http://teams.blabla.com/Shared Documents/Overview_NPD_Projects.xlsm")
    ' this does not work even when I change it to "Shared%20Documents"

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Project List")

    auxvariable = ws.Range("B2").Value

End Sub
```

The funny thing is that it works if I try to save the excel file manually to my desktop before running the macro and change the the path to:

```
Set wb = GetObject("C:\Users\Filipe.freitas\Desktop\Overview_NPD_Projects.xlsm")
```

I would save the file to the desktop and use the correct path, but I would need to refer to the excel file before doing it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `Set wb = GetObject(, "Excel.Application").Workbooks("Overview_NPD_Projects.xlsm")`?

Comment: David, unfortunately the code seemed to have stop working since a few days... Now it always give me the following error in the line that you have suggested: "Run time error '9'. Subscript out of range". Even though the excel name is the correct one... Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think that line will only work if the file is already open. If the file is not open, then that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DownloadFile.aspx and then

```
Dim xlapp as object
xlapp = createobject("Excel.Application")
set wb = xlapp.workbooks.open("thefilenamewhereyousavethedownload")
```